# Next/Previous post navigation

Tags: theme-development, next-post-link

Hey guys i want to make my next and previous links to work just for a category not all of them togheter,so when you get on the last post from that category to stop,right now it's still going in another category,can't fine the post_nav_link in my single.php....can you help me ? Here's a photo of my single.php[image: single.php]

Sorry for my bad english,thanks.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, for users like me posting from a mobile, your code in you image is totally unreadable. File an [edit] with your actual code. Tip: if you add code in the editor, highlight it and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your navigation can be found in this function:

```
sixteen_content_nav()
```

I just guess, but have a look into this file: inc/template-tags.php